80s/90s martial arts movie where a character trapped in a shield wall has his feet cut off
I think the movie was made in China. I think this version of the movie that I watched was an English dub.
Three characters that I remember the most are a chubby looking kid (I'll just call him chubby), a old/middle-aged woman who is a master at Martial Arts and one of the main villains henchman who wore robes and a cap.
I don't remember the setting, but I think it takes place during the late 1800s or very early 1900s.
Story Points:

This scene takes place during night and I think during a feast/party. Chubby goes into a room and finds roast chicken. As he begins feasting on it, the old/middle-aged woman appears and scares chubby. She then takes advantage and his fear and berates him for eating on her chicken.
Later, the party is then attacked by the villains minions (there are several dozens of them, perhaps hundreds) and proceed to kill many of the guests. One notable scene that I can remember is that one of the guests (male) is on the ground and dead guests fall between him. He then gets blood on his hands and proceeds to smear it on his face so that he can play dead.
Chubby, the old/middle-aged woman and several others of the party then escape, and the villain and his minions give pursuit.
Morning now. The group find arrive at a temple (I think) where they are met by monks. I think they provide shelter for the group
Night now. The monks are then attacked by the bad guys, and the monks master tries to combat them. The villains shield-wielding minions then proceed to trap him inside a shield wall/box, and the master's feet are caught by the shields. As he tries to escape, the scene then cuts to outside the temple and a clinging sound is heard (implying that the masters feet were cut off).
The old/middle-aged woman hears something outside and opens the rooms door where she meets a monk. She greets him, but then falls dead, and it is shown that he has been hit by dozens of small daggers/dart/arrows/spikes.
The group flee and the one of the villains henchman stated above appears before them. The old/middle-aged woman does a "you shall not pass" scenario and tries throwing daggers/spikes at him. He proves to be very quick and catches them. The old/middle-aged woman even spits at him and the henchman opens his mouth and swallows it. They then fight and it ends with the old/middle-aged woman victorious, but it is then shown that her back has been hit by several daggers/spikes, and then dies shortly.
The group arrive in a wax shop with human-sized wax sculptures, and they meet with the owner (who turns out to be a martial arts master). 
I can't remember anything else, but I think the final battles with the Villain ends inside the shop.


Was it kung fu, comedy style? If so, check out Stephen Chow's films, could be one of them. http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0159507/

None of them seem to match :( But thank you anyway for trying to help :)

If you are still looking for this movie, am pretty sure its Legend of the Red Dragon, also known as The New Legend of Shaolin starring Jet Li as the lead and Deannie Yip as the old woman.
I could not find the videos of the specific scenes but i got this link of the movie from youtube
point 2: starts at 50:10
point 4: starts at 01:08:50
point 5: starts at 01:10:12
point 7: starts at 01:15:08



